# Page flashes/flickers on every page load

Tags: performance

I recently started learning Wordpress, and i noticed something quite disturbing: 
Under most circumstances, every page load would cause parts of it to "flicker".

For instance, if i use the generic "twentyseventeen" theme, The famous header banner would flicker, each time i click a different link from the menu.

It feels as if "something is wrong" with the caching. I tried it both on my remote server and localhost- same result.

It seems that the problem is more severe on Chrome than on Firefox, but it's quite evident on both.

Here is a link to my example site: https://wp.ibrod83.com/. If you play with the top menu links, you should notice it.

I'll mention that i didn't make any special configuration, neither on the remote nor the local one.

Is this "normal" for WP? Can it somehow be fixed?

Comment: I see no flicker on the site you linked to, are you sure it's not a problem with your computer? Tested on Firefox and Chrome

Comment: What could be the problem on my pc(of course i will test it on other pc's, now that u raised this possibility)? Are you sure you played with the links in the header menu? There is no flicker in the home page.

Comment: I browsed through several pages to be sure, saw no flickering

Comment: No flicker here either, neither Chrome nor Firefox. Might be related to your machine.

Comment: Yes..probably. WSU, can you think of anything specific that might be causing it? Like some idea, off the tip of your head :D